# 2D arrays cross languages C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop

If I want to call an external C++ function which returns a 2d array, what kind of problems could I come across?  For instance, if I declare the 2D array inside of the C++ function and initialize the size of the array within the C++ function, how will the .Net automatic garbage collector handle this?  Do I have to give it a function which performs garbage collection and if so how do I call it from a C# program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the function returns a vector or vectors, it is the *exact* same problem in C++ as well.  It is a memory management problem, the caller of the function has no good way to free the memory of the array, it doesn't know the array sizes nor what allocator was used.  For that matter, even iterating the array is perilous.  A problem you can't fix in C++ cannot be fixed in managed interop either.

And you solve it the same way, you let the caller provide the array, to be filled by the callee.

Note that managed arrays don't have this problem, they are classes just like vector<>.  Returning a managed array from a function is not an issue.  C++/CLI can do it, the standard solution for difficult interop problems.  A SAFEARRAY is also a solution, tell the P/Invoke marshaller about them with [MarshalAs] in the managed declaration.

Comment: Thanks, that was very insightful!  By the way, I've read about this but I am not sure that I know what is meant when one talks about managed/unmanaged C++ code.

Comment: There is no such thing as managed C++ code.  The C++/CLI language resembles the C++ syntax.  Its compiler is capable of parsing C++ code *and* parsing managed classes.

Answer (score 0):

> how will the .Net automatic garbage collector handle this?

It won't, it has nothing to do with memory allocated by native applications.  You can return a copy of the array to the C# module and that takes care of that problem.  If it is very large and this would be a problem... well, maybe someone else has a better suggestion because I haven't yet had to cross that bridge =).  You'd likely allocate and destroy it in C++ code and return a pointer to the C# module. Careful with that though, and like I said, I haven't had to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know that for simple types, such as a string, the interop will make a copy of the unmanaged object and marshal it back to the caller.  At which point, the CLR will attempt to clean up the memory with a call to `CoTaskMemFree()`.  Whether this succeeds or not depends on how the memory was allocated.  If you can, use `CoTaskMemAlloc()` to allocate memory, which will allow the call to CoTaskMemFree() to succeed.

I've read that a failure to free the memory will result in a leak on XP, but will throw an exception in Vista and Win7... can't speak to the validity of that.

For more complicated types, such as an array, I'm not sure if that holds true.  However, an excellent method for freeing memory is in an article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jonathanswift/net-interop-freeing-unmanaged-memory).

The gist of it is to pass the data back as an IntPtr, then expose a method from the called dll called FreeMemory(), which takes the IntPtr and frees the memory allocated there.

HTH,
James

Comment: There's nothing special about the name `FreeMemory`, and writing it isn't enough, because C#/.NET won't call it automatically.  Write a function to free the array, give it a name of your choice, and call it from the C# code when it no longer needs to use the array.

Comment: Ben>  You're right, I just called it that arbitrarily... the key is that it's a method that you write to free the memory... there's nothing built-in.